# Should I trust Rails to pluralize tables correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**Tweet** to **tweets** is no big deal. 
And I assume **Country** would become **countries** without any fuss. I'd even credit them with **Cactus** becoming **cacti** (correct me if I'm wrong).

But what if I have class **Barnabus**? Do I call its table barnabuss, barnabi, or barnabusses?
What about **zxzzy**? How are non-english words handled?
Are there any non-messy options for overriding the decapitalization and pluralization?

I'm new to Rails and the modified table names have me a bit off-put. 
Links to relevant documentation are appreciated. [This is the only documentation I have seen relevant to this, and its not helpful](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-pluralize) for understanding odd exceptions for table names.

Forgive me if this is already covered, the results I got were not exactly what I'm trying to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trust it for most of the cases but if you have some doubtful model name with awkward plural names, you can always specify the table name in Model. e.g.

```
class SomeName < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'any_name'
end
```

Answer (score 6):

`String#pluralize` uses a heuristic with the rather simple general rules for the English language as a base and adding some known common exceptions.

Using `ActiveSupport::Inflector` you can customize its behavior.
In Rails projects you can find the inflections config at `config/initializers/inflections.rb`.

If you'd like to create a `Barnabus` model with a corresponding `barnabi` table then all you have to do is uncomment some inflections.rb content and explicitly tell Rails how to treat this word.

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'barnabus', 'barnabi'
end
```

P.S. Thanks to [Holger Just](https://stackoverflow.com/users/421705/holger-just) for the edit.

Answer (score 0):

If pluralization in views/error messages are your concern, in the situation that Rails fails magnificently with pluralizing a tricky table name you can add some localization to your app and tell it what you want it to use under various contexts. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models

Here's an example of pluralization rules in action:

```
activerecord:
    models:
      barnabus:
        zero: Barnabi
        one: Barnabus
        few: Barnabi
        other: Barnabi
```